# Pressing enter on LinkButton fires DefaultButton instead of focused LinkButton

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, defaultbutton

We have a code:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="ButtonNext">
    ...a lot of different controls...
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="ButtonPrev" OnClick="ButtonPrev_OnClick" Text="Prev"/>
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="ButtonNext" OnClick="ButtonNext_OnClick" Text="Next"/>
</asp:Panel>
```

When focus is placed on `ButtonPrev` and `Enter` is pressed, `DefaultButton` is clicked instead of `ButtonPrev`:

[image]

What can I do to modify this behavior? I am looking for simple solution.

I know I can wrap `ButtonPrev` in `Panel`:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="ButtonNext">
    <asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="ButtonPrev">
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="ButtonPrev" OnClick="ButtonPrev_OnClick" Text="Prev"/>
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="ButtonNext" OnClick="ButtonNext_OnClick" Text="Next"/>
</asp:Panel>
```

It is a solution, but it causes styling issues (additional `div`).

I know I can use JavaScript:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="ButtonNext">
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="ButtonNext" OnClick="ButtonNext_OnClick" Text="Next"/>
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="ButtonPrev" CssClass="DisableDefaultButton" OnClick="ButtonPrev_OnClick" Text="Prev"/>
</asp:Panel>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.DisableDefaultButton').on('keypress',
        function(e) {
            var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
            if (code == 13) { //Enter keycode
                $(this).click();
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    )
</script>
```

This solution I am using right now, but I don't like it.

Is there something I am not seeing?

Comment: Just out of curiousity: in what browser do you see this behavior?

Comment: @rene: I see this behavior in every browser (IE, Firefox, Chrome).

Comment: I hope you can go with the 'wrap ButtonPrev in Panel' method. try giving the inner panel css, display:inline-block

Comment: @AkhilSekharan: Wrapping button in panel is out of question. There are many places where I use `LinkButtons` and I won't wrap all of them.